# Generate a method returning a non-nullable simple type (int instead of int?)

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, openapi

I'm using Swagger-Codegen v2.0 to automatically generate an SDK based on my API, which is defined using Swagger.

My problem is: **I have an operation which returns an integer, the generated method in the SDK returns a nullable integer**. In the API description, it is well specified that this operations returns a 32 bits integer. I tried several modifications such as adding a default value of 0 in an operation filter but without successs.

Here is the operation json description:

```
"operationId": "GetSomething",
    "consumes": [],
    "produces": [
      "text/plain",
      "application/json",
      "text/json"
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "schema": {
          "format": "int32",
          "default": 0,
          ],
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
```

And here is the generated method prototype:

```
int? GetSomething();
```

Any insight would be welcome

Comment: FYI: `"required": [null]` is not valid here, remove it.

Comment: Yes thank you, it is the result of the different operation filters that I tried I have edited the question. Do you know any idea for that nullable problem ?